# Convert Cell Array of Symbolic Functions to Double Array of Symbolic Functions MATLAB

Tags: matlab, double, symbolic-math, cell-array, sym

I have the following:

```
syms x;
F = {3*x,2*x,x};
```

I would like to make `F` the following array `G`:

```
G = [3*x,2*x,x];
```

To do this, I have tried this:

```
G = double(F);
```

and this:

```
 G = double([F{:}]).';
```

Neither options work. Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: A “double” is a number, not a function nor a symbolic function. I think what you want to do is create a symbolic function that returns an array?

Comment: I don’t have access to the symbolic toolbox right now. Does `G = [3*x,2*x,x]` work? If so, then `G = [F{:}]` should work as well, I think.